# What programs should I use to get a picture of resource usage on Ubuntu ?

Tags: command-line, scripts

Every now and then my computer gets completely unusable. So unusable I can't even open a terminal and run `top` to figure out what is going on.

I want to create a script that collects data (cpu usage, processes running, memory, disk usage, network usage, whatever else might be useful to a diagnostic) so that I can reboot the computer and see what was going on.

This script will probably run every 10 seconds or so.

What program(s) should I use to obtain this information?

Note: `htop` and `iotop` seem to only work in a interactive mode. This is bad  if (as I assume) it prevents me from saving the data to a file

GUI programs might not be suitable, for the same reason (and for creating difficulties in automation)

Comment: When I need to track down apps causing 100% core util/drastic memory leaks, I almost always use a bash loop appending top to a file at a 10s interval (like you're planning). That's usually enough information to tie it down to an app, and remember if this issue occurs only infrequently, even top at 10sec intervals can end up generating a rather large file. You may want to consider something like a set of 1 hour bucketed files which start overwriting after 24hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `top` with parameter such as `-b` and `-d delay`.

In facts, from `man top`:

> -b : Batch-mode operation
>   Starts top in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or  to  a  file.

and

> -d : Delay-time interval as:  -d ss.tt (secs.tenths)
>               Specifies the delay between screen updates

The command `top -b -d 1 > mylog` put every second the output of top in the file mylog.